# Bordes de tabla php

Tags: php

hola amigos tengo esta tabla que me genera mi reporte en excel

```html
$mos.="<table border-collapse: separate; >


<tr>
        
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Solicitud Servicio</th>
     <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Folio</th>
                <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Mes</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Fecha</th>
   
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Departamento</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Area</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Tipo Servicio</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Descripción del trabajo</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Observaciones</th>
  <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Unidad</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Costo</th>
     
      </tr><tr><td></td></tr>
      ";
```

pero me sale sin borde quiero ponerle borde a mi tabla como lo hago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes agregar estilos a distintos elementos, por ejemplo aca poniendo table, tr, th, td le estas aplicando el mismo estilo a esos elementos que seria que tengan borde y que el texto este centrado.

```html
<style>
table, tr, th, td{
border: 1px solid #000000;
text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<table border-collapse: separate; >
<tr >
        <th bgcolor='#008000'>Solicitud Servicio</th>
           <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Folio</th>
                <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Mes</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Fecha</th>

        <th bgcolor='#008000'>Departamento</th>
        <th bgcolor='#008000'>Area</th>
        <th bgcolor='#008000'>Tipo Servicio</th>
        <th bgcolor='#008000'>Descripción del trabajo</th>
        <th bgcolor='#008000'>Observaciones</th>
        <th bgcolor='#008000'>Unidad</th>
        <th bgcolor='#008000'>Costo</th>
     
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: gracias tambien me gusto como quedo @Juan

Comment: De nada, en caso de que no hayas usado nunca podes investigar sobre bootstrap o materialize que te simplifican mucho el diseño, en ambos por ejemplo, si a la tabla le pones solo la clase "table" ya te la deja armada con estilos: Ej Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables  Ejemplo Materialize:https://materializecss.com/table.html

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte es que soy novata gracias @Juan

Comment: Todos lo fuimos, yo lo sigo siendo, si te intereso Bootstrap por ejemplo busca en youtube el canal de FalconMasters, tiene un tutorial de unos 40 videos donde muestra como usarlo de forma simple, yo aprendi con eso

Comment: ok lo hare muchismas gracias donde estes gracias@Juan

Answer (score 0):

```html
$mos.="<table border-collapse: separate; border= 1px; >


<tr>
        
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Solicitud Servicio</th>
     <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Folio</th>
                <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Mes</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Fecha</th>
   
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Departamento</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Area</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Tipo Servicio</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Descripción del trabajo</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Observaciones</th>
  <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Unidad</th>
        <th scope='col' bgcolor='#008000'>Costo</th>
     
      </tr><tr><td></td></tr>
      ";
```

Comment: gracias ya quedo @VirusDetected

Comment: De nada, no olvides marcarla como respuesta definitiva ;)

Comment: si lo estoy intentanto pero me dice que tengo que esperar mas tiempo